# Converting from wchar_t a char and vice versa

Tags: c++, encoding, char, wchar-t

I am writing a template class String (just for learning purposes) and have a small problem. If T is wchar_t and U a char and vice versa, what am I missing for this method to work?

```
template<typename U>
String<T> operator + (const U* other)
{
    String<T> newString;
    uint32_t otherLength = length(other);
    uint32_t stringLength = m_length + otherLength;
    uint32_t totalLength = stringLength * sizeof(T) + sizeof(T);

    T *buffer = new T[totalLength];

    memset(buffer, 0, totalLength);
    memcpy(buffer, m_value, m_length * sizeof(T));
    newString.m_value = buffer;
    newString.m_length = stringLength;
    memcpy(newString.m_value + m_length, other, otherLength * sizeof(T));

    return newString;
}
```

Ok, Jared below suggested a solution, so something like this (there are errors, I know, just a template)?

```
template<typename U>
String<T> operator + (const U* other)
{
    String<T> newString;

    uint32_t sizeOfT = sizeof(T); // wchar_t is 4
    uint32_t sizeOfU = sizeof(U); // char is 1

    T* convertedString;

    int i = 0;
    while (*other != 0)
    {
        convertedString[i] = ConvertChar(*other);
        other++;
        i++;
    }

    return newString;
}

template <typename U>
T ConvertChar(U character)
{

}
```

Comment: If all your character are ASCII a dumb wchar_t to char is good. in any other case, you need to convert Unicode to UTF8. http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your code is essentially using memory copies when converting from a `U*` to `String<T>`.  That's unfortunately not going to work because `wchar_t` and `char` have different memory layouts.  In particular a `wchar_t` usually takes up 2 bytes while `char` is a single `byte`.  What you need to establish here is a proper conversion function which should be applied to every item in the string

```
T ConvertChar(U c) { ... }
```

Comment: True. Besides that wchar_t <-> char conversion is not only truncation/extension of every element. It is so if your locale is English and you use only wchar_t in the interval [0, 256)

Comment: @Fallen yes that's close to what i would expect.  But now you need to integrate that into the loop.  Instead of doing `memcpy` you'll need to apply that transform to every char in the source string.

Answer (score 1):

While you could just widen when converting from `char` to `wchar_t` (i.e., use `wchar_t(c)`) but it is probably doing the wrong thing. When converting from `wchar_t` to `char` it is obvious that you are likely to loose information. It has become common that individual character entites actually do *not* represent individual characters but are actually just bytes representing UTF-8 or UTF-16. In that case the elements probably need to be encoded/decoded into the corresponding other representation. Obviously, the conversion isn't one to one: some Unicode characters consist of multiple UTF-8 bytes and multiple UTF-16 words.

You might want ot have a look at `std::codecvt<...>` for converting between encodings.